# I want to sum up my IncomingProduct Table's amount column if materialId and depotId columns are same. Finally i want to subtract these. MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to sum up my IncomingProduct Table's amount column if materialid and depotid columns are same and my OutgoingProduct Table's amount column if materialid and depotid columns are same. And finally i want to subtract total of incomingproducts from outgoingproducts if their materialid and depotid are same.

For Example: IncomingProduct Table:

[image]

For ex: OutgoingProduct Table:

[image]

For example, i want to write: there are stock of 4 products for 1 materialId and 2 depotId. ((5+3)-(3+1))

I tried this:

PRODUCTVIEWMODEL.CS

```
using StockControl.Models.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace StockControl.ViewModels
{
    public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Material> material { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<IncomingProduct> incomingProduct { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<OutgoingProduct> outgoingProduct { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Depot> depot { get; set; }
    }
}
```

INDEX.CSHTML

```
@model StockControl.ViewModels.ProductViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Stock Status</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tblMaterials">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Material Name</th>
            <th>Depot Place</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.IncomingProduct)
        {
            foreach (var item2 in Model.OutgoingProduct)
            {
                var stockIn = Model.IncomingProduct.GroupBy(x => new { x.depotId, x.materialId }).Select(x => new { stock = x.Sum(i => i.amount) });
                var stockOut = Model.OutgoingProduct.GroupBy(x => new { x.depotId, x.materialId }).Select(x => new { stock = x.Sum(i => i.amount) });
                if (item.Material.materialname == item2.Material.materialname && item.Depot.place == item2.Depot.place) {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Material.materialname</td>
                    <td>@item.Depot.place</td>
                    <td>@??What should I write here(stockIn-stockOut)??</td>
                </tr>
              }
            }
        }
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to cycle through each row on each different table just to check whenever they match, this is a performance hole. You should retrieve the totals of each one, join them and display them accordingly:

```
<tbody>
    @{
        // retrieve all incoming product totals (with materialId, depotId and total)
        var incomingProductTotals = Model.IncomingProduct
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.depotId, x.materialId })
            .Select(g => new
            {
                g.Key.materialId,
                g.Key.depotId,
                total = g.Sum(t => t.amount)
            });

        // retrieve all outgoing product totals (with materialId, depotId and total)
        var outgoingProductTotals = Model.OutgoingProduct
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.depotId, x.materialId })
            .Select(g => new
            {
                g.Key.materialId,
                g.Key.depotId,
                total = g.Sum(t => t.amount)
            });

        // join them and generate a new object with materialId, depotId and Total as the rest
        var totals = incomingProductTotals
            .Join(
                outgoingProductTotals,
                incoming => new { incoming.materialId, incoming.depotId },
                outgoing => new { outgoing.materialId, outgoing.depotId },
                (incoming, outgoing) => new
                {
                    incoming.materialId,
                    incoming.depotId,
                    Total = incoming.total - outgoing.total
                });

        foreach (var item in totals)
        {
            <tr>
            <td> @item.materialId </td>
            <td> @item.depotId </td>
            <td> @item.Total</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

You might want to consider doing this on the controller and only pass the filtered object on the Model to the view. Also seems that you want to display the material name and the depot place, but the join works by ID. You might need to recover the actual names from the database with a simple `db.Find()`, or add them as group by values.

Comment: If there is not OutgoingProduct for available depotid and materialid which are same with IncomingProduct, I want to write only total number of IncomingProduct to StockControl page( I want to take the total amount of OutgoingProduct as 0) How can I do?

Comment: Then you need to avoid the Join operation, do a foreach that cycles the incomingProductTotals and retrieve it's matching outgoing total to do the rest inside the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work. This creates an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous type with `depotId`, `materialId` and `Sum` as properties.

```
var groupedByFields = Model.IncomingProduct.GroupBy(x => new { x.depotId, x.materialId })
                              .Selct(g => new
                              {
                                  g.Key.materialId,
                                  g.Key.depotId,
                                  Sum = g.Sum(t => t.amount)
                              })
```

Then use `.FirstOrDefault` to get the Sum based on `materialId` and `depotId` for each row.

```
var sum = groupedByFields.FirstOrDefault(a => a.materialId == 1 && a.depotId == 2).Sum
```

Comment: I can not write directly equals to 1 or 2, because there are lots of material and depot id in my actual table. I updated my question, can you look pls?

Comment: That was just an example. In your case keep the `groupedByFields` code outside the `foreach`. Then inside the `td`, `<td>@groupedByFields.FirstOrDefault(a => a.materialId == item.materialId && a.depotId == item.depotId).Sum</td>`